# Image missing on html page on localhost server

Tags: html, eclipse, osx-yosemite

I'm learning HTML pages with javascript, and I made a very simple page which marquee's an image on the page, but I can only see an outline and not the image.
I'm using Eclipse Luna on Mac OS X Yosemite. 
I've created HTML pages on windows, and never faced a problem there.
so is there something wrong with Mac??

Edit : Also, I'm using the J2EE server to run the code, as the HTML preview server just won't start.

{

```
<marquee scrolldelay="10"><img src="/Users/rahulkhairwar/Downloads/Boulder-Bookstore_Sam-Hall.jpeg" height="500" width="500"></marquee>
```

}

[link to screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d6q3g79aip3p51w/Screen%20Shot%202015-06-23%20at%2009.59.08.png?dl=0)

Comment: Can you show us the page and image file?

Comment: yes, I've added the code and the link to the screenshot

Comment: For the `img` tag, use a `src` value off of the root of the web server or relative to the page. `/Users/rahulkhairwar/Downloads/Boulder-Bookstore_Sam-Hall.jpeg` is not a URI that the client should have access to.